# Geotools google maps java ee web application

Tags: google-maps, jakarta-ee, geotools

I'm searching the alternatives for developing a java web application to calculate land values based on some variables with a visual presentation of a map.

Since the data that i have is ESRI shapefiles and i want to go open source i ended up with this configuration.

1. Take the shp files with [Geotools](http://geotools.org/) , transform and store them in a MySQL spatial DB(or any other open source spatial DB).
2. Use of java EE(jsp,javabeans) for communication with the spatial DB and Geottols for calculating the value given a land-point and all variables needed(i.e. area value,distance from parks,distance from metro stations etc).
3. Use of Google Maps and Javascript API to get the land-point from user and also show some markers,lines,polugons(i.e. the metro stations,the parks etc)

I developed recently a less complex web app with the use of java ee(for connection with [Fusion tables](http://tables.googlelabs.com)) and google maps javascript api.
Nevertheless i don't have experience with gis calculations and i'm wondering if this configuration makes sense to an experienced developer.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PostGIS and GeoServer. 
You can write simple servlets to call into PostGIS to answer your spatial questions
You can use GeoServer to display maps from your postgis data sources.

It is easy to load shapefiles into both PostGIS and Geoserver

Don't use MySQL most of it's spatial functions are not implemented. They are there in the doc but they are not implemented in the code.

You could use the GMaps JS API or you could look at OpenLayers, which is an open source JS mapping library.